# Why does all non matching traffic go to the first VirtualHost rather than the default site config in httpd.conf

Tags: linux, apache, centos, virtualhost, httpd.conf

I have always wondered why all non matching traffic go to the first VirtualHost rather than the default site config in httpd.conf?

Lets assume httpd.conf has not been edited.

I create a file called `/etc/httpd/conf.d/vhost.conf`

With the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName website.com
        ServerAlias www.website.com
        DocumentRoot "/site1"
        <Directory "/site1">
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        Some Rules Here
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias www.example.com
        DocumentRoot "/site2"
        <Directory "/site2">
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        Some Rules Here
</VirtualHost>
```

This the above example, if you send a request for stackoverflow.com you would get filtered into the first vhost, no matter what the filters are rather than the default website in httpd.conf

What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You’re not doing anything wrong; that’s simply how Apache’s [Name-based Virtual Hosts](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html) work:

After you configure virtual hosts on Apache, the original default web server
(if any) becomes just another virtual host; there’s nothing special about the
web server that’s configured in `httpd.conf`. The default virtual host (for an IP address that Apache “listens” to) is simply the **first** one listed in the Apache configuration file(s):

> If you are adding virtual hosts to an existing web server, you must also create a `<VirtualHost>` block for the existing host. The `ServerName` and `DocumentRoot` included in this virtual host should be the same as the global `ServerName` and `DocumentRoot`. List this virtual host first in the configuration file so that it will act as the default host.

Also, from the same page:

> If no matching virtual host is found, then the **first listed virtual host** that matches the IP address will be used.
>
> As a consequence, the first listed virtual host is the *default* virtual host.  The `DocumentRoot` from the main server will **never** be used when an IP address matches the `NameVirtualHost` directive. If you would like to have a special configuration for requests that do not match any particular virtual host, simply put that configuration in a `<VirtualHost>` container and list it first in the configuration file.

---

The best overall description for how Virtual Hosts work on Apache that I have found is [An In-Depth Discussion of Virtual Host Matching](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/details.html). This also specifies that,

> The first name-based vhost in the configuration file for a given IP:port pair is significant because it is used for all requests received on that address and port for which no other vhost for that IP:port pair has a matching `ServerName` or `ServerAlias`. It is also used for all SSL connections if the server does not support Server Name Indication.
>
> The first vhost in the config file with the specified IP address has the highest priority and catches any request to an unknown server name, or a request without a Host: header field (such as a HTTP/1.0 request).

Comment: Thanks, that was a great answer, now so many things make sense.